# How to sort and list out the array element, after comparing the sums of each numeric value

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

This code returns only returns the order of the sums of the numeric value, how do I return the array element in a list arranged by largest sum on top?
For instance, the result should be:

```
"1234-2722-2343-2842"
"1234-2722-2343-2345"
"1234-2322-2343-2342"
```

Code:

```
var addSum = function(ccNum) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<ccNum.length; i++ ) {
        var eachLetter = ccNum.charAt(i);
        if (!isNaN(eachLetter)) {
            sum += +eachLetter;
        }
    }
    return sum; 
};

var ccNums = ["1234-2322-2343-2342","1234-2722-2343-2345", "1234-2722-2343-2842"];

var checkNums = [];

for (var i=0; i<ccNums.length; i++) {
    var ccNum = ccNums[i];
    var sum = addSum(ccNum);
    console.log("The checksum of CC number:"+ccNum+" is "+sum);
    checkNums.push(sum); 
}

checkNums.sort(function(a,b) {
    return b-a;
});

console.log(checkNums);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **[`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)** with help of **[`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)** and **[`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)** methods

```js
var ccNums = ["1234-2322-2343-2342", "1234-2722-2343-2345", "1234-2722-2343-2842"];

// function to get sum of numbers in string
function sum(str) {
  // split string
  return str.split('-')
    // iterate and get sum
    .reduce(function(a, b) {
      // parse string to convert to number
      return a + Number(b); // in case string contains no-digit char that for avoiding NaN use "return a + ( parseInt(b, 10) || 0 )
    }, 0); //set initial value to avoid 2 parsing 
}

// call sort function
ccNums.sort(function(a, b) {
  // find out sum and compare based on that
  return sum(b) - sum(a);
});

console.log(ccNums)
```

---

Or much better way would be, store the sum in an object and refer in sort function which helps avoid calling `sum` function multiple times.

```js
var ccNums = ["1234-2322-2343-2342", "1234-2722-2343-2345", "1234-2722-2343-2842"];


// function to get sum of numbers in string
function sum(str) {
  // split string
  return str.split('-')
    // iterate and get sum
    .reduce(function(a, b) {
      // parse string to convert to number
      return a + Number(b);
    }, 0); //set initial value to avoid 2 parsing 
}

var sumArr = {};

// create object for referncing sum, 
// which helps to avoid calling sum function 
// multiple tyms with same string
ccNums.forEach(function(v) {
  sumArr[v] = sum(v);
});

// call sort function
ccNums.sort(function(a, b) {
  // find out sum and compare based on that
  return sumArr[b] - sumArr[a];
});

console.log(ccNums)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `String.replace`, `String.split`, `Array.map`, `Array.filter` and `Array.reduce`:

```
var ccNums = ["1234-2322-2343-2342","1234-2722-2343-2345", "1234-2722-2343-2842"],
    getSum = function(num){
        return num.replace("-", "").split("").map(Number).filter(Boolean).reduce(function(prev, next){
            return prev + next;
        });
    };

ccNums.sort(function (a, b) {
    return getSum(b) - getSum(a);
});

console.log(ccNums);
```

The output:

```
["1234-2722-2343-2842", "1234-2722-2343-2345", "1234-2322-2343-2342"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use [Sorting with map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Sorting_with_map), because it uses only one iteration for the sum of a string and uses it until the sorts end. Then it rebuilds a new array with the sorted items.

```js
var ccNums = ["1234-2322-2343-2342", "1234-2722-2343-2345", "1234-2722-2343-2842"];    

// temporary array holds objects with position and sort-value
var mapped = ccNums.map(function (el, i) {
    return {
        index: i,
        value: el.split('').reduce(function (r, a) { return r + (+a || 0); }, 0)
    };
});

// sorting the mapped array containing the reduced values
mapped.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b.value - a.value;
});

// container for the resulting order
var result = mapped.map(function (el) {
    return ccNums[el.index];
});

console.log(result);
```